# Using case expressions in a calculated column postgresql

Tags: postgresql, casting, case, calculated-columns

*Edited to provide sample data*
I am trying to create a calculated column that sums 2 other columns, which should be easy. However, some values in both of the columns are null, so I want to use a case expression to replace null values in both columns with 0s and then add up the resulting values. The other complicating factor is that the second column contains text values with commas that need to be converted to numerical before I can add them. What I am currently trying to do is:

```
SELECT (case when pm."PS" is null then 0 else pm."PS" end) + (case when pm."PS-PREV1" is null then 0 else replace(pm."PS-PREV1", ',', '')::numeric end) AS "Sales"
FROM pm
```

Sample data:

| PS | PS-PREV1 |
| --- | --- |
| 20000 | null |
| 30000 | 20,000 |
| null | null |
| null | 30,000 |

Desired output:

| output |
| --- |
| 20000 |
| 50000 |
| 0 |
| 30000 |

This is just returning the value of the 1st column without adding in the second column. Where am I going wrong? Am I overthinking this?

Comment: please show us sample data and what you get right now and what is your desired output

Comment: @eshirvana just edited to provide sample data, thanks!

Comment: Your code works fine: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mJPmXiw7EgaLtBfPbEPkKg/0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code should work , however you can write it a little bit more clean:

```
SELECT COALESCE(pm."PS",0) 
       + COALESCE(replace(pm."PS-PREV1", ',', '')::numeric,0) AS "Sales"
FROM pm
```

Comment: Thank you- that is so much easier to look at and it works flawlessly